# Sequelize Cross-schema transactions

Tags: javascript, mysql, sequelize.js

**How to create a cross-schema transaction using Sequelize:MySql?**

Couldn't find anything at Sequelize docs yet this functionality is possible via MySql.

Assuming I'm creating two schemas (or databases in the MySQL terminology):

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const config = require("../config");


const UsersDb = new Sequelize(config.usersDatabaseName, config.username, config.password, config.options);

const ProductsDb = new Sequelize(config.productsDatabaseName, config.username, config.password, config.options);
```

Is there something like this?

```
await BothDBConnections.transaction(null, async (transaction) => {
      ///
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparently passing over the transaction works:

```
await UsersDb.transaction(null, async (transaction) => {
await ProductsDb.transaction({transaction}, async(t) => {
...
})
```